# Laravel model with multiple submodels

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

I am building an application which has a quite complex model (at least for me). I've been looking for solutions for a few days now and still not sure I understand the correct way to write this.

I have a "main" model, which is named EscalationPolicy.
The policy can have targets (1 or many): Team, User or Schedule (can be 1 of each, or even multiple of each and none of some).

For sake of simplicity, let's define the models as follow (*Account is a parent model that owns multiple models with hasMany relation*):

**EscalationPolicy**

```
account_id
name
"targets" (how to define this).
```

**Team**

```
account_id
name
```

**User**

```
account_id
name
email
```

**Schedule**

```
account_id
name
schedule_data (json)
```

What I am trying to achieve is to easily get the submodels from an EscalationPolicy, something like this:

```
$escalationPolicy = EscalationPolicy::find(1); //example
$targets = $ecalationPolicy->targets
//targets should be a collection of Team, User and Schedules associated to that policy.
```

I have tried to use polymorphic many-to-many relationship, but I am not able to have the correct output. Looking at the examples from Laravel' documentation ([Many To Many (Polymorphic)](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations)), I am not sure that is what I am trying to achieve, since I am not trying to use a single (Tag) model for multiple purpose (Post, Video) but rather have one model (EscalationPolicy) that can reference to multiple models (User, Team, Schedule).

Any idea if I can find a simple way to implement such thing?

Thanks a lot in advance,
ASM

Comment: Sounds like a polymorphic M:N relationship. Well, 3 to be more precise. EscalationPolicy <-- morph pivot -->  Team, EscalationPolicy <-- morph pivot --> User, EscalationPolicy <-- morph pivot --> Schedule.  You would need to define 3 methods (for the 3 relationships mentioned before) and then an accessor that just merges the 3 collections.

Comment: @IGP Thanks a ton!! That is exactly what I needed! I have created all morphPivots on EscalationPolicy with $this->morphedByMany. Inside EscalationPolicy I used the $with variable to eager load them as follow: $with = ['contacts', 'teams', 'schedules']. And have created an accessor that calls them all and returns a collection with collect()! Thanks once again!

Comment: You're welcome. Glad that worked for you. However, I advise you to avoid using the `$with` property and instead manually eager load the relationships inside your queries. `$with` often lead to unexpected amount of queries.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly a Polymorphic many-to-many relationship.

You can have it this way:

**EscalationPolicy**

```
account_id
name
```

**EscalationPoliciable**

```
escalation_policy_id
escalation_policiable_id
escalation_policiable_type
```

and all other tables are the same